# What is the expected value of a die given the outcome is prime?

Tags: probability, expected-value

We have a six sided die, what is the expected value of a die given the outcome is prime.

My solution:

Outcome is prime: This means it can be either $2, 3, 5$

$E(X) = (1/3)2 + (1/3)3 + (1/3)5$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I think those should be 1/3 as we already know the outcome will be prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you are missing nothing. (Except perhaps the person who asked you this also wants you to do the calculation and convert your answer into a number.)